# Can't access innerHTML of child element in sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, innerhtml

I have a sortable list like this:

```
<div id = "sortable">

         <div class = "sortableItem day">Monday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result1">Hotel 1</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result2">Hotel 2</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result3">Hotel 3</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result4">Hotel 4</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result5">Hotel 5</div>

</div>
```

I am trying to access different child elements of the div "sortable" but I only manage the first one - afterwards I get "undefined" returned.

So when I log:

```
sortable.childNodes[1]
```

I do get "Monday" returning in the console. But as soon as I change this to:

```
sortable.childNodes[2]
```

(or indeed any other index for that matter) I get undefined. I am sure I'm doing something incredibly basic wrong but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try using `children` instead of `childNodes`

`sortable.children[1]`

Answer (score 2):

`childNodes` includes white-space. You'll want to verify that the child node at that index is an element before you try to grab its `innerText` (which may be as simple as `if (sortable.childNodes[x].innerText) { /* use innerText */ }`).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already mentioned, you're accessing whitespace instead of the elements.

I put together a fiddle for you to get only the childNodes with a class of sortableItem :)

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoxey/g9tebkzw/

```
const sortable = document.getElementById("sortable")

//create loopable array from childNodes
const childNodes = Array.from(sortable.childNodes)

//filter through the array and remove anything that doesn't have a class of sortableItem as the first class name)
const children = childNodes.filter((node) => node.className ? node.className.startsWith("sortableItem") : false)


//do something with children here
console.log(children)
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with the `:nth-child` pseudo selector

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#sortable > :nth-child(1)').textContent)
console.log(document.querySelector('#sortable > :nth-child(2)').textContent)
console.log(document.querySelector('#sortable > :nth-child(3)').textContent)
```

```html
<div id="sortable">

  <div class="sortableItem day">Monday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result1">Hotel 1</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result2">Hotel 2</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result3">Hotel 3</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result4">Hotel 4</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result5">Hotel 5</div>

</div>
```

Comment: While `.querySelector` does work for this, it's perhaps a little more out of the way than just using `.children` and it's certainly not iterable in the same way that an array is by default.